# Group an array of objects based on a specific field

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by

I have an array of objects. I want to group them by a specific field.

```
[
    {
        "name": "JOHN",
        "type": 1,
        "sum": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "SERA",
        "type": 1,
        "sum": 43
    },
    {
        "name": "SERA",
        "type": 2,
        "sum": 129
    },
    {
        "name": "JOHN",
        "type": 2,
        "sum": 200
    }
]
```

The output I expect for grouping by name attribute is as follows.

```
{
    // Group #1

    "JOHN": [
      {
        "type": 2,
        "sum": 200
      }
      {
        "type": 1,
        "sum": 5
      }
    ],

    // Group #2

    "SERA":[
     {
        "type": 1,
        "sum": 43
     },
     {
        "type": 2,
        "sum": 129
     },
    ]
}
```

I used nested loops, but unfortunately the execution speed was slow and it did not give the right results.

Comment: can the output also be wrapped fully in `{ }` brackets ? so the full result is an object and not an array ? I guess otherwise it's not possible

Comment: @Saeed The output is not syntactically correct

Comment: @caramba Yes it can wrapped fully in `{ }` brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As if you mentioned, we can use an object instead of an array for the most outer wrapper. And also swap inside one object to an array, then this is a possible solution.

```js
var data = [{"name": "JOHN","type": 1,"sum": 5},{"name": "SERA","type": 1,"sum": 43},{"name": "SERA","type": 2,"sum": 129},{"name": "JOHN","type": 2,"sum": 200}];

var newData = {};

data.forEach( (item) => {

  if (!(item['name'] in newData)) {
      newData[item['name']] = [];
  }
  newData[item['name']].push(
      {
        'type':  item['type'],
        'sum' : item['sum']
      }
  );
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed output structure is not valid, however using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can create an object in which all the properties are arrays of objects:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "name": "JOHN",
        "type": 1,
        "sum": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "SERA",
        "type": 1,
        "sum": 43
    },
    {
        "name": "SERA",
        "type": 2,
        "sum": 129
    },
    {
        "name": "JOHN",
        "type": 2,
        "sum": 200
    }
];

const result = data.reduce((c, {name, type, sum}) => {
  c[name] = c[name] || [];
  c[name].push({type, sum});
  return c;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way with `forEach`, `destructuring` and `??` operator

```js
const merge = (arr) => {
  const obj = {};
  arr.forEach(({ name, ...rest }) => (obj[name] ??= []).push(rest));
  return obj;
};

const data = [
  {
    name: "JOHN",
    type: 1,
    sum: 5,
  },
  {
    name: "SERA",
    type: 1,
    sum: 43,
  },
  {
    name: "SERA",
    type: 2,
    sum: 129,
  },
  {
    name: "JOHN",
    type: 2,
    sum: 200,
  },
];

console.log(merge(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function which take advantage of  `Array.prototype.reduce` to transform the initial data to another structure of array.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "name": "JOHN",
        "type": 1,
        "sum": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "SERA",
        "type": 1,
        "sum": 43
    },
    {
        "name": "SERA",
        "type": 2,
        "sum": 129
    },
    {
        "name": "JOHN",
        "type": 2,
        "sum": 200
    }
];

function groupedBy(data, field) {
  let fieldValues = [...data].reduce((acc, current) => {
    return acc.concat(current[field]);
  }, []).filter((value, index, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  });
  
  let results = fieldValues.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let items = [...data].filter(el => {
      return el.name === item;
    });
    
    items.forEach(i => delete i.name);
    
    return Object.assign(acc, { [item]: items});
  }, {});
 
  return results;
}

console.log(groupedBy(data, "name"));
```